# jquery post not passing my function variable

Tags: php, jquery, variables, post

This is driving me mad. I'm passing two variables into a function that posts data to a PHP script and then into a database. Pretty simple stuff but I can get the php name part to pass, it just returns empty. I've looked at the $.post notes and everything looks ok:

```
function postData(phpvar, value) {
   $.post('scripts/insert.php', { phpvar: value }, function (data) {
       if (data == true) {
           alert('yes')
       } else {
           alert(data)
       }
   });
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the name like this...

```
var params = {};
params[phpvar] = value;

$.post('scripts/insert.php', params, function(data){
```

or like this...

```
$.post('scripts/insert.php', {phpvar:phpvar, value:value}, function(data){
```

Not sure which you're after.

Comment: So in the second example, will that be a 2 php variable? $_POST['phpvar'] == phpvar and $_POST['value'] == value ?

Comment: @jhodgson4: Probably. I don't know anything about PHP, but they will be two separate values. You can change the keys to something else if you want. `{foo:phpvar, bar:value}`

Comment: Ok I see, so is there no way of setting the first part with a variable also? so phpvar[ php variable name]: value [ value ]?

Comment: @jhodgson4: Not inline, but you can do it if you first create the object, then add the property/value pair after. See the first example I gave.

Comment: Ahhhh, thanks so much for your help, works a treat. Thanks again.